# Logcat error, get no sensor list out of easy program

Tags: java, android

Hy everyone!

I have this easy program to find out my sensor.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textview=findViewById(R.id.tv);
    sensorManager= (SensorManager) getSystemService((Context.SENSOR_SERVICE));
    deviceSensor=sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    textview.setText(deviceSensor.toString());
}
```

But every time want to run it collaps instantly.
So i tried logcat this brought me to this error, i don´t really understand why this occurs.

```
2022-02-02 21:42:55.762 18946-18946/com.example.showsensors E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.showsensors, PID: 18946
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.showsensors/com.example.showsensors.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.showsensors.MainActivity> has no zero argument constructor
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.showsensors.MainActivity> has no zero argument constructor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1083)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: does the class have some method like `public MainActivity(){}`

Comment: Yes i got this. I use this template from an empty activity and i hav no errors in my code.
Should i use another package like com.example.showsensors? I also got all required imports for that.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say. if you don't have that method, add it.

Comment: if you don't add it, it will crash

Comment: Yes i use the public MainActivity(){} method. I also have no errors in my code.

Comment: can you send the code of the entire class?

Comment: I finally found the bug. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: what was it? you can post it as answer so that it helps people in future